# Solve and put in interval notation $4x^3 - 81x< 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is: Solve $4x^3 - 81x < 0$ and express the solution set in interval notation.

I got $(-9/2,0)\cup(9/2,\infty)$ but I don't think its right. I factored it out to $x(2x+9)(2x+9)$

Comment: I got (-9/2,0)U(9/2,Infinity) but I don't think its right. I factored it out to x(2x+9)(2x+9)

Comment: You are very close in your answer and should add those details.

Comment: Hint:$x(2x+9)(2x-9)$ is the correct factorization.

Comment: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ahh yes I see that now MAthNoob thanks! What am I doing wrong after that though?

Comment: Wade, I think you misread the inequality sign as $>$ instead of $<$. Your answer is correct if the sign is >.

Comment: Is it (-9/2,0) U (0,9/2) U (9/2, infinity)?

Comment: I'm confused at how it is right if the sign is switched?

Answer (score 1):

After you factor the polynomial, you must determine the zeros and do a line analysis.

\begin{align*}
4x^3 - 81x & < 0\\
x(4x^2 - 81) & < 0\\
x(2x + 9)(2x - 9) & < 0
\end{align*}

The expression on the left hand side of the inequality is equal to zero when $x = 0$, $x = -9/2$, $x = 9/2$.  Since $4x^3 - 81x$ is continuous, these are the points where $4x^3 - 81x$ can change sign.

We have to consider the sign of $4x^3 - 81x$ in the four intervals $(-\infty, -9/2)$, $(-9/2, 0)$, $(0, 9/2)$, and $(9/2, \infty)$.  The sign of $4x^3 - 81x$ is determined by the signs of the three factors $x$, $2x + 9$, and $2x - 9$.  The line analysis below shows the sign of each factor in each interval.  When an odd number of these linear factors is negative, the product $4x^3 - 81x$ is also negative.  Hence, the solution set is $S = \left(-\infty, -\dfrac{9}{2}\right) \cup \left(0, \dfrac{9}{2}\right)$.

[image: line_analysis_of_cubic_inequality]

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps 
$$ 4x^3-81x\lt 0 $$
$$ x(4x^2-81)\lt 0 $$
$$ x(2x+9)(2x-9)\lt 0 $$
$$ x\left(x+\frac{9}{2}\right)\left(x-\frac{9}{2}\right)\lt 0 $$
Therefore the solution set is
$$ \left(-\infty, -\frac{9}{2}\right)\cup \left(0, \frac{9}{2}\right) $$